# Why is Google Analytics capturing unmanipulated page paths despite using GTM regex table to clean page paths up?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

**UPDATE:** Allowing my GTM updates some time over the weekend resulted in my changes being reflected in GA with having clean page paths. There were a portion of users who were using a previously cached version of GTM but allowing the updates to run over a few days resulted in the most recent version being used by all users by Monday.

The following is how GA and GTM are installed on the site:

1. The site is a SPA (Single Page Application) using Angular 2.
2. The Front-end team installed GTM and enabled the **dataLayer** object
3. Front-end team is pushing an event "**pageview**" and then routing page path to the dataLayer **key:value**; for example: **"pagePath":"/this/page-path"**
4. In my GTM container I have a GA tag triggering on a "**pageview**" custom event
5. In my GA tag I have "**Enabled overriding settings in this tag**" with the following:
   [Screen capture of my GA tag configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kQJJ.png)
6. My Regex Table variable is configured as such:
   [screen capture of my regex table configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40AnL.png)
7. Here are a few unmanipulated page paths I want to clean up by removing the digits and query parameters:

   - /pages/projectDetails/200345
   - /thankYou?projectId=MjI4NDcw&projectName=UG9saWNlIERlcGFydG1lbnQgRGlzcGF0Y2ggQ2VudGVyIFQuSS4
   - /pages/projectSetup1/224124
   - /pages/projectSetup2/224124
   - etc...
8. When debugging in GTM and visiting those page paths, the output is exactly as shown in the screen capture
9. When using Chrome's inspector > Network > search for "collect"; the "**dp**" parameter shows the output I have setup in my regex table
10. In GA I do **NOT** have any filters enabled to manipulate request URIs

What I am experiencing is the first row in my regex table is being respected because in GA I am seeing the expected output of **/pages/projectDetails**; but subsequent rows are not being respected.

When reviewing **Behavior > Site Content > All Pages** GA is still getting the unmanipulated page paths such as:

- /pages/projectSetup1/224124
- /pages/projectSetup2/224124
- /thankYou?projectId=MjI4NDcw&projectName=UG9saWNlIERlcGFydG1lbnQgRGlzcGF0Y2ggQ2VudGVyIFQuSS4
- etc...

**NOTE:** At one point I had Search and Replace filters in GA enabled that successfully manipulated the page paths to make them cleaner. I disabled those filters in favor of GTM regex table doing the job but I am experiencing issues.

I do not understand what I am missing OR if I misconfigured something OR something I am not thinking about?

Any suggestions to point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The aim to move the logic from GA filters to GTM makes perfect sense. That's what we've been doing too. I usually don't use regex tables though, but just custom JS cleanup. Regardless, if you're able to always see correct dp in the network call, that means that GTM does its part perfectly. What you might be missing is that other tags might not have your overriding. Try doing this dp setting through a Settings variable rather than overriding and set it for every tag. Also try to find examples where the dp parameter is wrong. That will help with debugging.

Comment: Depending on how many hits you see, there might be a cached version of the GTM script out there that does not include your changes (GTM sets cache headers, but e.g. proxy servers in big offices do not necessarily respect them). I tend to send the version of the GTM container along as a custom dimension, so I can check if any issues occur for specific container versions.

Comment: @EikePierstorff - Thank you for this insight. I allowed the updates I made in GTM to run over the weekend. I saw my updates reflected in GA with clean page paths. Thanks for the suggestion of sending GTM container version as a custom dimension.

Comment: @BNazaruk - I'll take your suggestion using Custom JS to perform page path cleanup. I bet doing so will improve performance of GTM a bit better.

Comment: I voted to close this question because you indicate that you resolved the problem without receiving any answers.  If you still need answers, please [edit] the question to indicate that the issue is not fully resolved.  If the solution you found would be useful to others, please answer your own question by pressing the "Answer Your Question" button.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Looks like SO Meta gives the option to post comments as answer. I prefer it over letting the question die: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments I feel awkward doing this, but it seems better than the alternatives. I feel like this is a non-trivial question and should not be just closed.

Comment: Thanks for posting and answer. I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

*I'll compile the answer for it to not appear as unresolved question for whoever finds it later.*

The aim to move the logic from GA filters to GTM makes perfect sense. That's what we've been doing too. I usually don't use regex tables though, but just custom JS cleanup.

Regardless, if you're able to always see correct dp in the network call, that means that GTM does its part perfectly. What you might be missing is that other tags might not have your overriding.

Try doing this dp setting through a Settings variable rather than overriding and set it for every tag. Also try to find examples where the dp parameter is wrong. That will help with debugging.

Concating **Eike's** answer:

Depending on how many hits you see, there might be a cached version of the GTM script out there that does not include your changes (GTM sets cache headers, but e.g. proxy servers in big offices do not necessarily respect them).

I tend to send the version of the GTM container along as a custom dimension, so I can check if any issues occur for specific container versions.