# Deleted tags in Tag Manager but events are still coming to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have deleted some tags in Tag Manager, and published changes. But for some unknown reason I still see events coming in Google Analytics. Have doublechecked all tags, triggers & variables. How is it possible?  Any help or guidance is highly appreciated!

Comment: Please check all the tags once again there needs to be some event in some tag!

Comment: See my comment here (same question really): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69748164/why-is-google-analytics-capturing-unmanipulated-page-paths-despite-using-gtm-reg#comment123305247_69748164. If you published recently, the GTM script might be cached somewhere and you have to wait a while.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons for it:

1. Make sure it's not a cached version of GTM. In this case, you could use a custom dimension where you store your GTM version for production users. Then in GA you would be able to easily check if all those who still have the event have the old GTM version.
2. Go through the site where this event used to fire and try triggering it again, see if it fires for you.
3. Make sure you're not firing the event elsewhere by mistake. Check the page dimension for these events to check if it fires where you don't expect it.

This should solve the issue in vast majority of cases.

Comment: Appreciate your time. I am not a TM expert, so pardon me if it is basic.
How do I check if it is a cached version? Having said that I have only recently found the issue, so after that lots of other versions have been deployed, so how probable it is that it is a cached version...?

Comment: The number of versions deployed doesn't matter. Usually the number of cached containers decreases with time. You can track them in a custom dimension, setting it through gtm, using the container version variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply! I hopefully followed your advice correctly, and created a custom dimension with container_id&version. In customs report in GA, those events seem to be related to the latest version of TM container (which does not include that tag and trigger anymore)...

Comment: Great. That means that 2 and 3 are the things to check now.